# Passing a BinaryExpression as parameter

Tags: c#

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(this
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    ReplaceExpressionVisitor leftVisitor = 
                                new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr1.Parameters[0], parameter);
    Expression left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);

    ReplaceExpressionVisitor rightVisitor = 
                                new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], parameter);
    Expression right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(left, right), parameter);
}
```

Since I have another method where the only difference is the expression in the return statement, how to pass `Expression.OrElse` as a parameter to the method (my other method uses `AndAlso`)?

Since the methods are close to identical I would like one common method with the expression passed as a parameter.

I've tried passing a `BinaryExpression` without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about that?

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BinaryOp<T>(this
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, 
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2,
                            Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> operation)
{
     ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

     ReplaceExpressionVisitor leftVisitor = 
                 new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr1.Parameters[0], parameter);
     Expression left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);    
     ReplaceExpressionVisitor rightVisitor = 
                 new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], parameter);

     Expression right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(operation(left, right), parameter); 
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(this
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
     return BinaryOp(expr1, expr2, Expression.OrElse); // passed as mth group
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
     return BinaryOp(expr1, expr2, Expression.AndAlso); // passed as mth group
}
```